# How to get the man page of an option of a command?

Tags: linux, terminal, manpage

I want to jump straight to the description of an option of a command. Something like `man ls -la` or `gcc -g` or `cat -n` etc. you get it.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I typically do is in a man page hit `/`, and then type something to search.

Or if you want to jump directly to a section you could use `man --pager`. For example, if you wanted to go to the section about `-h` of `ls` you could do `man --pager='less -p -h' ls`. This could easily be made into a little bash script if you want to use this all the time.

If you want to jump directly to a section, and avoid hangups add 4 spaces in front of the section like so, `man --pager='less -p "    -h"' ls`.

Comment: the problem with this that it jumps to the first occurrence of the parameter not to the description. Eg. if there is a short description of the often used options in the head of the man page, then it shows that.

Comment: Well, you'll have to make your search more specific. So, I see that if I do `man --pager='less -p -l' ls` it hits the `--author` section which references `-l`. To make it more specific adding a tab to the front of the search will go directly to the description, like this `man --pager='less -p "    -l"' ls`. Seeing as all description subsections have tabs in front of them, this could be scripted for your desired effect. I'll add an example in my main post.

Comment: Sure but this is not exactly what I am looking for. Maybe there is no way to do that. I am trying to make your solution work with gcc -g but it won't work

Comment: ... I can't figure out how to do multiple spaces in markdown in the comments, but pretend there is 4 spaces before the `-l` in that last command in my previous comment.

Comment: The syntax provided will allow you to jump straight to the description of a command which is exactly what you said you were looking for. You can easily clean this up by adding it into a bash script like `man --pager='less -p $2' $1` call it something like manjump, and then call it with `manjump ls -l` and it will be pretty smooth.

Comment: Ok it works with 4 spaces!! Edit your answer please and I eill accept it! Thanks